# View all products on List page

Tags: shopware

I need to add a view all button to my list page. The sample projects given in shopware have implemented this using select box to display any number of products per page.

How can I convert this functionality to display all products?

Or, at least if someone can give me a hint about how to get total number of products in a particular category I can find a solution somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Since Shopware 5 has been released there is an "infinite scrolling" feature out of the box. It can be enabled/disabled in the theme settings of your current selected shopware frontend theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this via the Shopware Backend. Just set *Artikel pro Seite* and *Auswahl Artikel pro Seite* to a large number.

Go to **Einstellungen - Grundeinstellungen - Storefront - Kategorien/Listen**

[image: Shopware Backend]